# submit data per post after validation jquery applied doesn't work ($_POST empty)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I have a problem with Jquery, AJAX and field validation.

The validation works, the redirect works if everything is fine with input,but my values from fields are not contained in `$_POST` array.

**Here is the form start tag:**

`<form class="smart-form" id="register-form" method="post" action="#pages/target.php" novalidatee>`

**Here the JavaScript part:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">              
        // Load form valisation dependency 
loadScript("js/plugin/jquery-form/jquery-form.min.js", runFormValidation);


// Registration validation script
function runFormValidation() {
    //e.preventDefault();
    var $checkoutForm = $('#register-form').validate({

    // Rules for form validation
        rules : {
            name : {
                required : true
            },
            vorname : {
                required : true
            },  
            passwort : {
                required : true,
                minlength: 8
            },
            passwort2 : {
                required : true,
                minlength: 8
            },
            email : {
                required : true,
                email : true
            },          
            admin : {
                required : true,
                min: {
                  // min needs a parameter passed to it
                  param: 1
                }
            },
        },

        // Messages for form validation
        messages : {
                /* My Messagees*/ not mentionend

        },
        // Ajax form submition
        success : function() {
                     form.submit();
                    $('#register-form').addClass('submited');
                },


        // Do not change code below
        errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        }
    });        
};
```

Comment: `form.submit()` is **NOT** Ajax!  And it would **NOT** go inside the `success` option.  It only belongs in the `submitHandler ` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading through the [documentation for the validate method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate) of that plugin, I found out that you should be using the `submitHandler` callback when you actually want to submit a valid form.

> **submitHandler (default: native form submit)**:
>
> Callback for handling the actual submit when the form is valid. Gets the form
>   as the only argument. Replaces the default submit. The right place to
>   submit a form via Ajax after it is validated.

**And as @Sparky mentioned:**
*You typically would not need the success option unless you want to utilize the error label on a valid element like for a green checkmark or something.*

> **success Type: String or Function()**
>
> If specified, the error label is displayed to show a valid element. If a String is given, it is added
>   as a class to the label. If a Function is given, it is called with the
>   label (as a jQuery object) and the validated input (as a DOM element).
>   The label can be used to add a text like "ok!".

So, instead of placing the `form.submit();` bit inside of the `success` callback, you should place it inside of `submitHandler`.

**So your code should look something like this:**

```
// Optional, read what this does
success: 'valid', 

// This does the actual form submitting
submitHandler: function (form) {
    form.submit();
},
```

By the way, `form.submit()` is not AJAX, from what I understand, it just submits the form in the traditional way.

Comment: Correct.  However, you typically would not need the `success` option unless you want to utilize the error label on a valid  element like for a green checkmark or something.  Yes, `form.submit()` is the default form submit behavior.  For `ajax()`, you would remove it and insert the Ajax code in its place.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I added that to the answer.